# Show a centered div 100% of the viewport on iPhone and iPad when it is within a centered div with backround image and link

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, viewport

At the moment the used code centers a div with a width of 980px in a background div which contains an image with a link. This works fine on PC, Apple and Android. When the resolution is more than 980px, you see the background image equally on both sides. On Android phone or tablet you see 100% of the maincontainer div. But on iPhone and iPad, the maincontainer div aligns to the left and you see about 200px of the background div on the right side. I tried a lot of things, but I can't get it to act on iPhone and iPad like it does on Android devices: the maincontainer div 100% of the viewport. 
My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style>
html {
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #FFF;
}

body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#020051;
line-height:14px;
text-align:center;
background-size: 100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position: center top;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#background_with_link{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:2400px;
left:50%;
display: block;
margin-left:-1200px;
text-align:center;
}

#main_container{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:980px;
left:50%;
margin-top:103px;
margin-left:-490px;
margin-bottom:50px;
margin-right:auto;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="background_with_link">

<a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank"><img src="/UserFiles/Banners/image.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>

<!-- Main Container start -->
<div id="main_container">

</div>
<!-- Main Container end-->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope there is a solution for this. Thanks!

Erwin